# Как мне узнать размер объекта json

Tags: android, json

[image: Скриншот json]

Так выглядит `Json`. Как мне узнать размер объекта (`jsonOject`), который находится в `data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По документации есть публичный метод `length()`, им и воспользуйтесь
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#length()

Answer (score 3):

`length()` – возвращает длину массива:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\"]");
int arraySize = jsonArray.length();
```

Comment: Да это и дурак знает, а ничего что у меня вместо квадратных скобок фигурные, от туда  и вопрос. Говорят это норма, но если норма то как размер узнать то